# Error Running batch file from Windows desktop to execute a Java program in eclipse workspace

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, file, batch-file

I have a Java standalone project in Eclipse with about 10 packages. I have a main method(in eclipse)  that when executed from Eclipse works fine.

I have written a batch file to run it from the desktop. I just click the batch file and hope to run the program.

My code for the batch file is as follows.

**RunExecuteMyProg.bat**

```
echo Output of the Program
echo ---------------------

java C:\eclipse_workspace\eclipse\myprogram\MainProgram\ExecuteMainProgram

echo "Program Executed"
```

This program when run in Eclipse, usually takes between 1 -4 min depending on a number of factors. But when I click the .bat file, it opens for a fraction of a second and closes. Java is on my classpath. At command prompt when I try to compile, I get compile errors saying that some class is not found. However on eclipse it just runs fine. Log files need to get created when this program runs, but nothing happens from batch file.

PS: The class files are created in the same folder as the source files.

Comment: did you creating a jar file and running that?

Comment: @ant...no....I was reading on that. I tried, but it gave me an error. "The declared package "org.apache.log4j.net" does not match the expected package. Looks like some issue with having the source and .class files in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

You will know the problem if you open a command prompt and enter that command you have there:

```
java C:\eclipse_workspace\eclipse\myprogram\MainProgram\ExecuteMainProgram
```

It could be that you don't have java in the path or your program is written so that it has to have its current working directory where the program is located, etc etc.
Or any number of things. Get the output from executing that command manually in a command prompt.